# MSSQL: Display Rows for a Select with Case and Count even if Count = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, case

i hope i can explain my Problem in detail, so you guys can understand me.
Ive created a small example.

I have a Table which looks like this:

```
City       |    Name

Berlin     |    Mike
Berlin City|    Peter
Stuttgart  |    Boris
```

here is my Query:

```
    SELECT CASE
            WHEN City like '%Berlin%' THEN 'Count Person in Berlin:'
            WHEN City like '%Stuttgart%' THEN 'Count Person in Stuttgart:'
            WHEN City like '%Dresden%' THEN  'Count Person in Dresden:'
            ELSE 'unknown'
            END AS Text,
            COUNT(Name) AS countPersons
     FROM tblTest
     GROUP BY City
```

This is the result:

```
Count Person in Berlin:     2
Count Person in Stuttgart:  1
```

But my desired result is:

```
Count Person in Berlin:     2
Count Person in Stuttgart:  1
Count Person in Dresden:    0
```

how can i get my desired result? hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64920/1/0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have a table with the list of cities, then you can use a subquery.  The key to solving this type of problem is `left outer join`:

```
select cities.city, count(t.city) as numpeople
from (select 'Berlin' as city union all
      select 'Stuttgart' union all
      select 'Dresden'
     ) cities left outer join
     tbltest t
     on t.city = cities.city
group by cities.city;
```

If you want to have `'unknown'` as well, then `full outer join` can be used:

```
select coalesce(cities.city, 'unknown') as city, count(t.city) as numpeople
from (select 'Berlin' as city union all
      select 'Stuttgart' union all
      select 'Dresden'
     ) cities full outer join
     tbltest t
     on t.city = cities.city
group by coalesce(cities.city, 'unknown');
```

Comment: +1 However, i'm missing the `CASE` with the `Count Person in ...` part.

Comment: Thanks this helps me a little bite, but like Tim said the Case part is not clear and my main prob is that for example in the city Column for one person is 'Berlin' and for another one 'Berlin City' so i have to select with like '%Berlin%'. sorry my example was not good enough, i will edit it

Comment: Could you use the `IN` operator for this, @Gordon ?

Comment: @Newbie . . . It is not obvious to me where `in` would be used.